# "Sum" over logical and?

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus

Given a continuous sequence of integers $(a, a+1, a+2, \dots, b)$ I want to write:

$P_a \wedge P_{a+1} \wedge P_{a+2} \wedge \dots \wedge P_b$

Where $P_i$ is some logical statement parametrized by $i$

I have been writing:

$\forall_{i=a}^{b}P_i$

for this.

Is there a more correct and commonly used symbol for this?  Or a better way to write it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\bigwedge_{i=a}^b P_i$$

Where the symbol is `\bigwedge`